# How to see if there is a hidden admin role with an account that has no admin access?

Tags: users

I'm completely new to Drupal. A friend has asked me to help out with his Drupal 7 site. He created an account for me - but I'm thinking that the role given to my user account isn't really an admin account. When logging in, I don't see any way to administer modules, user permissions, etc.

I'm thinking that the admin role is hidden. For a person who is just now learning Drupal, what would be the easiest way to see if there is a hidden admin role?

Answer (score 1):

> ... For a person who is just now learning Drupal, what would be the easiest way to see if their is a hidden admin role?

***`Talk to your friend`***, and perform these steps:

- **Step 1**: ask for a screenprint (created by your friend, while your friend is logged in) of the list of roles shown via relative path `admin/people/permissions/roles` ... That will show you all "roles" defined in your site. Typically you'll have at least these 3 hardcoded (= delivered with Drupal) roles:

  - anonymous user (in the Drupal database this corresponds to `role id = 1`).
  - authenticated  user (in the Drupal database this corresponds to `role id = 2`).
  - administrator (in the Drupal database this corresponds to `role id = 3`).
- **Step 2**: find out what the "user id" is for the user that you received, which you'll typically see (as part of the relative path) when you try to edit your own profile.
- **Step 3**: ask for a screenprint (created by your friend, while your friend is logged in) of the granted roles shown via relative path `user/uid/edit` (whereas `uid` in it corresponds to your own user id) ... That will show you all "roles" you have been granted. Probably the role "administrator" will not have been granted.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hidden roles. You should have your user account login, and you should also have the user 1 (root user) login. That is the god user account.

Comment: Hey Kevin - thanks for helping out. I have my user account login, which has the role of "BB Site Admin". Since that role has a customized name, I'm wondering if that really isn't a root user login.

Comment: For instance, when going to "/admin/people/permissions/" I get the "Access Denied" page.

Comment: Role names don't matter because they don't dictate permissions. A role could be called "admin" but that doesn't really mean anything. User ID *1* is _always_ root user and _always_ exists. You need that login. You could also use the command line tool `drush` to do `drush uli` and get a reset link to the site to update the password. You could also go into the database, edit the user 1 email address in the users table, then do a forgot password on the site for that user to get it sent to yourself. From there, you can then update permissions for roles to be more permissive for higher level access

Comment: If someone deleted user id 1, that is bad, you need a way to get that back.

Comment: Thanks! Just looked at the profile for user 1, and they appear to have a role that I can not see (no roles are selected). Gonna have to track down that person.

Comment: User 1 does not need any roles. It is the designated super user in Drupal. It is not permission checked for anything.

Comment: Gotcha. So it appears that the super user created a role for site administrators, but hasn't given that role to look at permissions, modules, content filtering, etc. 

Steps to fix would be a) track down the super user, have him/her log in and change permissions, or b) go in to the database and edit his user profile.